# How do I sort Glassdoor reviews by rating on a computer?

Tags: sorting, glassdoor.com

The [Glassdoor mobile app](https://help.glassdoor.com/article/Filtering-Reviews-on-the-Glassdoor-mobile-app/en_US) in both iOS and Android has an option to sort and filter reviews.  As far as I know this does not exist on the computer version of the Web App.

How do I sort Glassdoor reviews by rating?